# LexException: f-string: trailing junk in field

Tags: hy

In doing the following, I'm getting the error `LexException: f-string: trailing junk in field`:

```
(nixos-install #* ctx.args
               :I (with [f (open (+ resources "/flake.lock"))]
                        f"nixpkgs=https://github.com/nixos/nixpkgs/archive/{(D (.load json f)).nodes.nixos-22-05.locked.rev}.tar.gz")
               :m/run True
               :show-trace True
               :install-bootloader install-bootloader
               :option "tarball-ttl 0")
```

What exactly does this mean?

Comment: I think you can probably figure this one out. Look at your replacement field and consult the documentation for f-strings. How do you expect Hy to parse the field?

Comment: I don't get it; it's accessing an attribute of a function output, is it not? `D` refers to the `Dict` function from [the Python addict module](https://github.com/mewwts/addict).

Comment: It is not. `(f).attr` is not legal Hy.

Comment: Oh, right! Sorry; I forgot. Would it be possible to implement a better error message here, specifying something like a syntax error? Should I open an issue on the GitHub repo for this?

Comment: I think this error message is correct, and is more helpful than "syntax error" because it's more specific, but you can open an issue if you want to and see if other maintainers agree with you.

Comment: I'll try opening an issue, then; basically, I wanted Hy to tell me what you did, that `(f).attr` is not valid. Doesn't it usually state that if not in an f-string?